# How can I convert an location id in a trie to its position id ? Verilog

Tags: verilog, trie

In this binary trie's position ID, the left son element would take 0, and the right son would take 1. So level 0 is the root 0, level 1 is element 1 and 2(two sons of 0), level 3 is 3, 4(two sons of 1), 5, and 6 (two sons of 2). For location id 6, the position id will be 11.(the first 1 is the right son of 0, and second 1 is the right son of 2).
I was wondering what is the way to convert the location id like 6 to its position id (11) in one clock or the least the better.

For example:

```
6  -->  11

12 --> 101
```

Thank you

[image: Picture for the trie structure]

Comment: Can you graphically present your scenario, or give more explanation?

Comment: Can you show you verilog implementation of a trie? that might help guide the answer as it is very abstract at present.

Comment: @PrakashDarji Thanks for reply, I made a picture for the trie, in this case, if given number 13, how could we get 110?

Comment: @Morgan Thank you for the reply, actually that is not a storage structure,  please check the new updated picture is my question. For example, for give number 13, how could we get its position ID 110? Thank you

Comment: If your trie is fixed and not changed in adaptive manner then make lookup table.

Comment: Also note that, your output position id can not have variable size, for 6 it is 2 bit and for 13 it is 3 bit. it is not possible, instead use other terminology or mechnism

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that, not supporting variable output width, See bellow code, It might help you.

```
module find_id ( 
                 input wire [3:0] loc_id, // 1 to 14
                 output reg [2:0] pos_id
               );

reg pos_1, pos_2, pos_3;

always @ (*)
begin
  pos_1 = (loc_id == 4'd2)
        | (loc_id == 4'd5 | (loc_id == 4'd6))
        | (loc_id >= 11); 

  pos_2 = ( pos_1 & ((loc_id == 4'd6 ) | (loc_id == 4'd13 ) | (loc_id == 4'd14 )))
        | (~pos_1 & ((loc_id == 4'd4 ) | (loc_id == 4'd9  ) | (loc_id == 4'd10 )));

  pos_3 = ( pos_1 &  pos_2 & (loc_id ==  4'd14))
        | ( pos_1 & ~pos_2 & (loc_id ==  4'd12))
        | (~pos_1 &  pos_2 & (loc_id ==  4'd10))
        | (~pos_1 & ~pos_2 & (loc_id ==  4'd8 ));
end


always @ (*)
begin
  pos_id = ({3{(loc_id <= 4'd2)                    }} & {pos_1, 1'bx, 1'bx})
         | ({3{(loc_id <= 4'd6)  & (loc_id >= 4'd3)}} & {pos_1,pos_2, 1'bx})
         | ({3{(loc_id <= 4'd14) & (loc_id >= 4'd7)}} & {pos_1,pos_2,pos_3}) ;
end

endmodule
```

For verification see TB:

```
module tb;

reg [3:0] loc_id;
wire [2:0] pos_id;

find_id find_id_0(loc_id,  pos_id);

initial
begin
  loc_id = 4'b0;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd10;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd9;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd13;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd6;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd8;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd11;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd7;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd4;
  #100 loc_id = 4'd12;
  #100 $finish;
end

initial
  $monitor ("loc_id = %d pos_id =%b",loc_id, pos_id);

endmodule
```

After Simulation result would be like that:

```
# 10.4

# vsim -lib work tb -c -do "run -all; quit -f" -appendlog -l qverilog.log -vopt 
# ** Note: (vsim-3813) Design is being optimized due to module recompilation...
# //  Questa Sim-64
# //  Version 10.4 linux_x86_64 Dec  2 2014
# //
# //  Copyright 1991-2014 Mentor Graphics Corporation
# //  All Rights Reserved.
# //
# //  THIS WORK CONTAINS TRADE SECRET AND PROPRIETARY INFORMATION
# //  WHICH IS THE PROPERTY OF MENTOR GRAPHICS CORPORATION OR ITS
# //  LICENSORS AND IS SUBJECT TO LICENSE TERMS.
# //  THIS DOCUMENT CONTAINS TRADE SECRETS AND COMMERCIAL OR FINANCIAL
# //  INFORMATION THAT ARE PRIVILEGED, CONFIDENTIAL, AND EXEMPT FROM
# //  DISCLOSURE UNDER THE FREEDOM OF INFORMATION ACT, 5 U.S.C. SECTION 552.
# //  FURTHERMORE, THIS INFORMATION IS PROHIBITED FROM DISCLOSURE UNDER
# //  THE TRADE SECRETS ACT, 18 U.S.C. SECTION 1905.
# //
# Loading work.tb(fast)
# run -all
# loc_id =  0 pos_id =0xx
# loc_id = 10 pos_id =011
# loc_id =  9 pos_id =010
# loc_id = 13 pos_id =110
# loc_id =  6 pos_id =11x
# loc_id =  8 pos_id =001
# loc_id = 11 pos_id =100
# loc_id =  7 pos_id =000
# loc_id =  4 pos_id =01x
# loc_id = 12 pos_id =101
# ** Note: $finish    : find_id.v(56)
#    Time: 1 us  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb
# End time: 09:58:04 on May 18,2016, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0
```

Comment: I got another try: Subtracting the location ID by the first number in it's level then we will get the position ID. For example: For ID 12, we get 1100 - 111 = 101. And 101 is the position ID for 12